# SAS reading data from file containing tab and comma delimiters

Tags: sas

So the problem is that tab delimiter is defined as '09'x , and comma - ",". I know that you can use multiple delimiters if you have for e.g. colon and comma and define it as ":," but i dont know how to define multiple delimiter of tab and comma. My data file looks like this:

```
AisleLevels: 14, Enroute: 10, OrderAvg: 2, PSnum: 2, PStype: 1, AisleSLots: 150, NOP: 1                 
    Run 1   Run 2   Run 3   Run 4   Run 5
    RN Set 1    RN Set 2    RN Set 3    RN Set 4    RN Set 5
ElevUtil    0.147   0.147   0.149   0.139   0.142
MSutil  0.186   0.186   0.189   0.174   0.182
PickUtil    0.417   0.424   0.417   0.394   0.407
TPut    668 678 666 632 649
```

First row is delimited with comma, and everything else with tab.. Thank you everyone for help!

Answer (score 2):

I would not use multiple delimiters; I would read the whole thing as tab delimited, and parse the first line separately.

Something like this:

```
data want;
infile datalines dlm='09'x truncover;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
input @1 str $1500.;
*(parse string with SCAN);
 Levels=scan(str,1,',');
 Enroute = scan(Str,2,','); /*etc.*/
end;
else input 
(run1-run5) $
/*....*/
;
run;
```

Usually I would only output after a non-first-row and retain the first row variables as well, if that's what you need (having those variables on all rows).  I also don't totally understand your format; do you really want 5 rows from that data (beyond the first)?  Then it is a slightly different DP issue.